# JOOQ SQL Syntax conversion with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, h2, jooq

I have an SQL script export in SQL CE syntax. When my app starts, jooq should read this script, parse it to h2 compatible sql, and then read the create and insert statements into my h2 db. Unfortunately I seem to cannot get JOOQ running under spring boot.

I read some tutorials but so far, I was best off with spring boot tutorials by Baeldung. This time however it does not work, since my Autowired dataSource is always null. But apperently spring boot should have configured it by itself.

I stuck to this tutorial post: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-support-for-jooq

Any one know what is missing here?

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hotcueconverter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hotcueconverter</name>
    <description>hotcueconverter</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
# Own settings
server.port=${8080}
# H2 Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db/MIKStore
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
# H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=H2
```

ApplicationConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.hotcueconverter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext defaultDSLContext() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(this.configuration());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSourceConnectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(this.dataSource));
    }

    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        final DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
        jooqConfiguration.set(this.dataSourceConnectionProvider());
        jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(this.exceptionTranslator));

        return jooqConfiguration;
    }
}
```

Since the exceptionTransformer is not mentioned in the tutorial, I wrote my own exceptionTranslator:

```
package com.example.hotcueconverter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext;
import org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext defaultDSLContext() {
        return new DefaultDSLContext(this.configuration());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSourceConnectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(this.dataSource));
    }

    public DefaultConfiguration configuration() {
        final DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
        jooqConfiguration.set(this.dataSourceConnectionProvider());
        jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(this.exceptionTranslator));

        return jooqConfiguration;
    }
}
```

My TestModule/Service where the data
PS: this.loadFile just loads the sql script.

```
@Service
public class TestModule {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestModule.class);
    private static final String MIKSTORE_FILENAME = "mikstore_export.sql";

    @Autowired
    DefaultDSLContext dslContext;

    public void test() throws Exception {
        final String fileAsString = this.loadFile(MIKSTORE_FILENAME);

        final Parser parser = this.dslContext.parser();
        final Queries queries = parser.parse(fileAsString);

        this.dslContext.execute(queries.toString());
    }
```

Any help, even if it is another way to achieve this would be highly appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:**

I found the issue :D I was using a DSL not managed by spring , hence it was null because i did not initialize it by myself.

I also had my hibernate DDL properties in the applciation properties set wrong. Since  I want to use jooq to create schema and data i had to set hibernate auto ddl to none